# How to order array of objects by the number of the keys the same as the given ones as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, lodash

I have a basic object with some keys, and the list of objects with similar, but not necessarily the exact same, keys.

```
const o1 = {k1: "", k2: "", k3: ""} // the basic object
const o2 = {k1: "", k4: ""}         // 1 the same key
const o3 = {k1: "", k3: ""}         // 2 the same keys
const o4 = {k3: "", k1: "", k2: ""} // 3 the same keys
const o5 = {k5: ""}                 // 0 the same keys
```

I want to write a function which takes the base object and an array of other objects, and it will sort/order them by the number of similar keys in the given object.

```
function order(obj, arr) {
  // ...
}
```

The result should be the ordered array of the given objects based on the number of the same keys as the base object.

```
order(o1, [o2, o3, o4, o5])
// result: [o4, o3, o2, o5]
```

What would you use for that?

I was thinking about sorting by the length of intersection on objects keys.

Comment: `Object.keys()`, `Array.sort()` and any form of loop to check/count the matching properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Object.keys` and `filter` to determine the "real" length of the array and `sort` appropriately:

```js
const o1 = {k1: "", k2: "", k3: ""} // the basic object
const o2 = {k1: "", k4: ""}         // 1 the same key
const o3 = {k1: "", k3: ""}         // 2 the same keys
const o4 = {k3: "", k1: "", k2: ""} // 3 the same keys
const o5 = {k5: ""}                 // 0 the same keys

function order(obj, arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => 
              Object.keys(b).filter(k => k in obj).length - 
              Object.keys(a).filter(k => k in obj).length);
}

console.log(order(o1, [o2, o3, o4, o5]));
```

Comment: Just a caveat: `Array.sort` will mutate `arr`, which may be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could count same keys and take this value for sorting.

```js
const
    o1 = { k1: "", k2: "", k3: "" }, // the basic object
    o2 = { k1: "", k4: "" },         // 1 the same key
    o3 = { k1: "", k3: "" },         // 2 the same keys
    o4 = { k3: "", k1: "", k2: "" }, // 3 the same keys
    o5 = { k5: "" };                 // 0 the same keys

function order(object, array) {
    function getCount(o) {
        return Object.keys(object).reduce((s, k) => s + (k in o), 0);
    }
    return array.sort((a, b) => getCount(b) - getCount(a));
}

console.log(order(o1, [o2, o3, o4, o5])); // [o4, o3, o2, o5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash:

```
function order(reference, objs) {
  const referenceKeys = _.keys(reference);
  return _.sortBy(objs, obj => -_(referenceKeys).intersection(_.keys(obj)).size());
}
```

Another way:

```
function order(reference, objs) {
  const referenceKeys = new Set(_.keys(reference));
  return _.sortBy(objs, obj => _(obj).keys().sumBy(key => referenceKeys.has(key) ? -1 : 0))
}
```

Comment: I really like the first example!